# Python selenium webscraping

Tags: python, selenium

```
<td ng-repeat="cell in item.datum track by $index" ng-switch="cell" ng- 
if="item.rowType!=&quot;chart&quot;" class="ng-scope">
            <!-- ngSwitchWhen: null -->
            <!-- ngSwitchWhen: undefined -->
            <!-- ngSwitchWhen: _PO_ -->
            <!-- ngSwitchDefault:  --><span ng-switch-default="" class="ng- 
            binding ng-scope">68.40</span><!-- end ngSwitchWhen: -->
        </td>

<td ng-repeat="cell in item.datum track by $index" ng-switch="cell" ng- 
if="item.rowType!=&quot;chart&quot;" class="ng-scope">
            <!-- ngSwitchWhen: null -->
            <!-- ngSwitchWhen: undefined -->
            <!-- ngSwitchWhen: _PO_ -->
            <!-- ngSwitchDefault:  --><span ng-switch-default="" class="ng- 
            binding ng-scope">-19.81</span><!-- end ngSwitchWhen: -->
        </td>

<td ng-repeat="cell in item.datum track by $index" ng-switch="cell" ng- 
if="item.rowType!=&quot;chart&quot;" class="ng-scope">
            <!-- ngSwitchWhen: null -->
            <!-- ngSwitchWhen: undefined -->
            <!-- ngSwitchWhen: _PO_ -->
            <!-- ngSwitchDefault:  --><span ng-switch-default="" class="ng- 
            binding ng-scope">-2.59</span><!-- end ngSwitchWhen: -->
        </td>
```

Hi I am trying to get the values 68.40, -19.81 and -2.59 within the code using python selenium. However, when I use css_selector I keep getting error. Can someone give me the correct code to locate and produce the values without calling the value itself. Thanks alot!

Comment: *"when I use css_selector I keep getting error"*... Share your code and exception log

Comment: As a new user it is best to always post as much code as possible to help users answer your question. It is always a best practice

Comment: @jy.chua Additionally, update the question with the parent node of all the 3 child `<td>` nodes.

Answer (score 0):

To access the text of an element using Python's selenium

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name("className").text
```

Use the `.text` to access the elements text.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("ng-binding")
for element in elements:
    print(element.text)
```

Or if you can't use class name, use a css selector as you said.

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying me! When I followed the code you gave, the output returns nothing. What should I do?

Comment: Can you update with your code copied? You should step through or use prints to try and debug, is your webdriver working properly?